# How to put edit button in php that will show modal in bootstrap?

Tags: php

I am trying to Edit my data in bootstap modal, but i don't know how to put **href** in button that will trigger the modal

I am Trying the Following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM masterlist_tbl";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$number_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$query = "SELECT distinct(student_num) FROM masterlist_tbl";
if($number_rows>=1){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$table.="<tr class='td-ojt-student'>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[0]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[1]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[2]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[3]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[4]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[5]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[6]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'> ".$row[7]." </td>
<td class='th-ojt-student'>
// Edit Button
        <a href='?Edit_1=".$row[0]."'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit-company'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>
            </span>
        </button>
        </a>
</td>
</tr>";
}
$table.="</table>";
}else{
$table.="<tr><td colspan='18' align='center'>NO Data</td></tr></table>";
}
echo $table;
```

Comment: You are adding the modal inside the `a` tag with a `href` value added to it. On click it will take you that that link and will not open the modal.

Comment: use jquery onlclick event

Comment: `PHP` is evaluated on the server. If you want to have a modal that appears 'on click' then you are going to want to add a client-side language like `javascript`

Comment: how can i get the id of data row with the use of Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: If you want to show the modal then you do not give <a> tag before button as it will redirect you to the link given.